# How to break page title in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to break a page title of the **Joomla 3** website into two lines.

Can admin add `<br>` tag between page title field in the back end? for e.g. 'Home[br]Page'

Comment: It's possible but, I don't know of any quick and straight-forward way of doing this, nor I have heard of any plugin. You may want to try out this question in [JSE](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Override the following constant

`JPAGETITLE` and give it a value `%1$s <br> %2$s`

in `Extension > Language Manager > Overrides`

Comment: There is nothing like JPAGETITLE in Joomla's Constant list. hard luck!

Comment: There is man ... :)  I override the joomla page title to remove `-` in between the site name and the page name for the site http://outpostis.com/